# Help with ieee.cls and figure?

Tags: incompatibility

Using [{ieee}[2000/01/11].cls](http://mocha-java.uccs.edu/ieee/ieeeftp/ieee.cls) (via [Formatting IEEE Papers in LaTeX2e](http://mocha-java.uccs.edu/ieee/)), I have a problem with the following minimal code (*which builds fine for `\documentclass{article}` - using `pdflatex` to compile*):

```
\documentclass[%
        %draft,
        %submission,
        %compressed,
        %final,
        %
        %technote,
        %internal,
        %submitted,
        %inpress,
        %reprint,
        %
        %titlepage,
        notitlepage,
        %anonymous,
        narroweqnarray,
        inline,
        %twoside,
        ]{ieee}
% \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

Test ...

\begin{figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It fails with:

```
! Too many }'s.
\color@endbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup 

l.33 \end{figure}

? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

This error is discussed in [LaTeX Community • View topic - color package incompatible with figures?](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=4766&start=0), and indeed, [ieee.cls](http://mocha-java.uccs.edu/ieee/ieeeftp/ieee.cls) does define `\@xfloat` - but I'm trying the following things:

```
\makeatletter

% \undef\@xfloat % no work :) 

% http://joonidea.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-undefine-command-in-latex.html
% \let\@xfloat\@undefined                  % undefine \@xfloat
% no work, fails with:
%% ! Undefined control sequence.
%% \@xfloat #1[#2]->\caption@ORI@xfloat 
%%                                      {#1}[#2]\caption@settype {#1}
%% l.49 \end
%%          {figure}

% http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=507&p=1978
% the below has no effect: 
% \let\latex@xfloat=\@xfloat
% \def\@xfloat #1[#2]{%
%   \latex@xfloat #1[#2]%
%   \def \baselinestretch {1}\@normalsize  %%  GT: need \@normalsize?
%   \normalsize
% }

\makeatother
```

... but obviously, cannot get it to work.

Is it somehow possible to have `\figure` with this `{ieee}[2000/01/11]` class, such that I override its behavior in the tex file, instead of hacking the .cls file?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: The `ieee` class is ancient. You really should be using the current `IEEEtran` class.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that @Joseph Wright - I will try to modify my document towards `IEEEtran`; but I'd still be interested in an answer to the OP, in case it turns out people insist on the "old" layout... Cheers!

Comment: Just a note on `IEEEtran`: `ieee.cls` commands like `\authorinfo` or `\journal` are not present in `IEEEtran`, which also ignores the `\documentclass[...]` arguments as given above (and insists on twocolumn layout).

Comment: @sdaau : actually it doesn't. It has many capabilities and you can check the extensive documentation. You can use for example `\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}`. Moreover, as far as I know, all IEEE journals are converted to `IEEEtran` class maybe except the IEEE computer society and other few journals. So whoever is forcing `IEEE.cls`, simply does not follow IEEE regulations.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification, @percusse - sorry for using imprecise wording, I merely wanted to emphasize different behavior between packages; also nice to know I shouldn't expect the old `ieee.cls` to be forced! Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau No problem at all. I just wanted to let you know that days of `ieee.cls` has passed and you shouldn't spend your precious effort on obsolete tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with

```
\makeatletter
\let\kernel@xfloat\@xfloat
\makeatother
\documentclass[...]{ieee}

\makeatletter
\let\@xfloat\kernel@xfloat
\def\@floatboxreset{%   
  \reset@font
  \linespread{1}\normalsize
  \@setminipage}
\makeatother
```

and the result seems to be the desired one. I believe that the problem lies in a very old definition of `\@xfloat` that is incompatible with the way LaTeX normally works with floats.

Using a class that is based on a LaTeX 2.09 document style along with much more modern packages leaves the door open for inconvenients, as you've discovered.

Comment: Yippie !! :) Awesome - many thanks for the solution, @egreg; a true life-saver this time :) Cheers!